# Need help to convert conventional java to streams

Tags: java, java-stream

In the following code I am trying to remove all nodes and leaves that do not have a root in the key of input map. Input is the Map<rootId: String, listOf(root,nodes,leaves)>

Working logic

```
@NotNull
private static Map<String, List<Element>> removeOrphanNodes(Map<String, List<Element>> mapOfAllProcesses) {
    Map<String,List<Element>> refinedRootMap= new HashMap<>();

    for(Map.Entry<String,List<Element>>entrySet: mapOfAllProcesses.entrySet())
    {
        if(entrySet.getValue().size()>1)
            refinedRootMap.put(entrySet.getKey(),entrySet.getValue());
        else {
            Element loneElement = entrySet.getValue().get(0);
            if (entrySet.getKey().equals(loneElement.getIdAsString()))
                refinedRootMap.put(entrySet.getKey(),entrySet.getValue());
            else if(loneElement.getCurrentOperations()!=null && loneElement.getCurrentOperations().iterator().next().getId().toHexString().equals(entrySet.getKey()))
                refinedRootMap.put(entrySet.getKey(),entrySet.getValue());
        }
    }
    return refinedRootMap;
}
```

The above code works as expected. I wanted to make use streams to achieve the same functionality but getCurrentOperations throws null pointer

My Attempt

```
return mapOfAllProcesses.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size()>1 || entry.getValue().stream()
            .anyMatch(
                    element-> element.getIdAsString().equals(entry.getKey())||element.getCurrentOperations().stream().findFirst().get().getId().toHexString().equals(entry.getKey())
            )).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: What advantage do you think will be obtained by converting your already-working code to use streams?

Comment: Is the appearance of `loneProcess` in your method intentional?  That is not declared anywhere in your method, so is it then an instance variable?  Or did you mean for that to be `loneElement`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger loneProcess is loneElement I will edit the question.
With streams, I wanted to see if it can be simplified using some operations

Comment: If it works, don't change it.  Streams should make your life easier, but not if you have to rewrite your code to use them.  And quite often they aren't as efficient as loop driven code.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't do this.

The Stream API is not a replacement for loops or conventional iteration constructs.

Ideal code for putting into a Stream would be something that:

- Does one function (reads data out, loads data in)
- Could be parallelized
- Has no side-effects (e.g. doesn't reach out to anything else)

Your code satisfies the last bullet, I'm not sure about the middle bullet and it definitely does a lot more based on conditions, which...isn't *ideal* for streaming.

Maybe a better way to approach this problem would be to re-think the data structure you're using?  You're using a `Map<K, List<V>>`, and that can be contextualized inside of a [Guava Multimap](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).  Maybe that's where the first improvement needs to happen - using a more suitable data structure for this instead?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid raising NPE when collection returned by `element.getCurrentOperations()` is `null` you might try to use `Stream.ofNullable()`. And dummy default value while extracting result from the optional can help in cases when this collection is empty (and consequently optional would be empty).

```
return mapOfAllProcesses.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entrySet.getValue().size() > 1 ||
        entry.getValue().stream()
        .anyMatch(
            element -> element.getIdAsString().equals(entry.getKey())
                ||
            Stream.ofNullable(element.getCurrentOperations()).findFirst()
                .map(operation -> operation.getId().toHexString())
                .orElse("").equals(entry.getKey())
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue
    ));
```

It is worth to note that both snippets (imperative and functional) are extremely convoluted, so it would be wise to consider extracting some pieces of functionality into separate methods.

Comment: The null check before match will fail the condition where the currentOperation can be null or empty and in that case the key is compared with element id

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, but I don't think there's any advantage to be gained this way.  It's slightly shorter, but not really any simpler, and definitely not any *clearer*.

```
@NotNull
private static Map<String, List<Element>> removeOrphanNodes(Map<String, List<Element>> mapOfAllProcesses) {
    return mapOfAllProcesses.entrySet().stream().filter((entry) -> 
            (entry.getValue().size() > 1)
                || entry.getKey().equals(entry.getValue().get(0).getIdAsString())
                || Optional.ofNullable(entry.getValue().get(0).getCurrentOperations())
                           .stream()
                           .map((ops) -> ops.iterator().next().getId().toHexString())
                           .anyMatch((s) -> s.equals(entry.getKey()))
        ).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

This version handles the fact that `getCurrentOperations()` can return `null` by capturing the return value as an `Optional`.  The `Optional`'s stream will be empty when `getCurrentOperations()` returns `null`, and `anyMatch()` returns `false` on an empty stream.

The `map()` of the inner stream could be omitted in favor of a more complex predicate for its `anyMatch()`, but I think the version with `map()` is clearer.